# Rails Minitest inconsistent data after setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I've been hitting my head with following issue with no luck:
Trying to test that a rake task populates some tables correctly, I have following configuration:

```
class InitialDataTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, only: %w[centres projects departments]
    System::Application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['populate_lookup_tables:commit'].invoke

    sign_in users(:test_user)
  end

  test 'projects are created' do
    puts " Projects: #{Project.count}"
  end

  test 'centres are created' do
    puts "Centres: #{Centre.count}"
  end

  test 'departments are created' do
    puts " Departments: #{Department.count}"
  end
end
```

My rake task actually works as expected (in development, for instance) however, for the test it seems that only 1 table is being populated:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 15362
Started with run options --seed 17058

:: Centre populated successfully
:: Project populated successfully
:: Department populated successfully
>> OperationType is not empty
>> DocumentType is not empty
>> RecordErrorType is not empty

Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 1
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:51272
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Departments: 5
Centres: 0
Projects: 0
3/3[========================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:03, Time: 00:00:03

Finished in 3.88633s
3 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Coverage report generated for Unit Tests to <My Stuff> (28.45%) covered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rake task can be only invoked once in a given context. If you want to run it again you need to call `Rake::Task['populate_lookup_tables:commit'].reenable` first.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Can you point out any resource where I can get more info related to this or similar topics?

Comment: I found it here http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rake/Rake%2FTask%3Areenable